# How can I specify a startscript for my dockercontainer in Jenkins(Pipeline)?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, docker-container

I have configured my Jenkins to run our Build Jobs and functional Tests in a docker container. For example, when I click on the "Build Now"-Button - Jenkins will build the Dockerfile which is in Git and run the container so the Buildsteps (Jenkinsfile) can be done in this container.

My Question is now: How can I specify a startscript for my Container in the Jenkins-Pipeline?
Thanks for any tips.

Comment: What about `COPY startscript.sh /var/startscript.sh` and `CMD /var/startscript.sh` in your Dockerfile?

Comment: Thanks. But this copies the startscript.sh into the filesystem of the container. I want to run this script when the container is starting.

Comment: yes, this is done via `CMD /var/startscript.sh`. If you don't want to copy the script, you also can mount it at runtime via `docker run -v /path/to/my/script:/var myimage /var/script.sh`

Comment: It will depend on what plugins you are using. For example, if you use the [Docker Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Pipeline+Plugin) you [may not be able to use `ENTRYPOINT` because of how containers are provisioned](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41316).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a string(i.e. the startscript name) as an [input parameter](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/) in your Jenkins pipeline, so that you can conditionally specify which script to run.

Then you can mount the appropriate script at runtime in your jenkins pipeline config.

`docker run -v /path/to/script:/var imageName /var/${START_SCRIPT}.sh`